# After uploading images in the magento product is unable to show

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

i encountered a really weird problem in my website. If i am adding a product with images then it failed to load my website completely and also the product is not showing properly. My images and media directory permission are 755.Any solution for this?

Comment: which hosting you are using? if it is godaddy then change Options -MultiViews.
Some time images not show due this also.

Comment: Old product images are showing in list view and in product detail view it is not showing anything. EVen if i am adding a new product with images then it is not showing my product on the frontend and also it failed to load my website fully. I am using godaddy hosting

Comment: what is the permission of your media folder and sub folders?

Comment: All are having 755 permissions and if i am trying to change it to 777 my whole products not showing anything

Comment: try with 777 permissions

Comment: I changed the permission to 777 and it does not helped me before :(

Comment: have you set 777 permission of only media folder or all files and folders which are under media?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48063/discussion-between-oh-what-a-noob-and-urfusion)

Comment: Nope only to catalog inside of media folders

Comment: try with 777 permission to all file and folder inside media/catalog

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename **.htaccess** file within **magento/media/** folder and check once again.

Hope it would help.

For more check this link -

> http://magentomaster.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/magento-product-image-not-showing-on-front-end/

Comment: I changed the htaccess inside of media folder still the problem persists

Comment: Follow the link. May be you can there your solution.